# How do I use sed to insert a line into a configuration file?

Tags: sed, include

What's the best way to use sed to insert:

**include /etc/nginx/sites-directives/*.conf;**

into a file, **/etc/nginx/sites-available/VIRTUALSERVER_DOM**

on a line right after:

**fastcgi_read_timeout 60;**

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -i '/fastcgi_read_timeout 60;/ a\
include /etc/nginx/sites-directives/*.conf;' /etc/nginx/sites-available/VIRTUALSERVER_DOM
```

Explain: when reach `fastcgi_read_timeout 60;`, add a line (after) `include /etc/nginx/sites-directives/*.conf;`

Comment: I forgot to add a $ in front of VIRTUALSERVER_DOM (virtualmin environment variable) and it worked beautifully.

Comment: This is a minor issue, but it throws up an error on deleting the domain.  I am using this with Virtualmin "Command to run after making changes to a server", so would it be possible to have it add the line only if the /etc/nginx/sites-available/$VIRTUALSERVER_DOM file exist, so it won't try to add the line when deleting a domain?

Comment: try by adding `[ -f "/etc/nginx/sites-available/$VIRTUALSERVER_DOM" ] && ` before the sed command

Comment: It responds with: "Post-creation command failed" when I delete a domain.  Creating still works as expected.

Comment: i don't use Virtualmin so cannot test. In a batch is it the same ? manual run give an error ?

Comment: essentially virtualmin allows to run a command when creating/deleting domain.  When creating a domain, the file /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com will exist and your sed command works as expected.  When deleting the domain, the file /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com gets removed and then the sed script is looking for it, causing it to report the error.  Is it possible to check if the file exist first before sed, and if not, to just exit the command?